# Complex series where ratio test is not applicable, even though all coefficients are non-zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to see an example of a power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$, ($a_i\in\mathbb{C}$), which satisfies:

1) the series has positive (and finite) radius of convergence.

2) $a_n\neq 0$ for all $n\geq 0$.

3) the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $a_n=2^n$ when $n$ is even and $a_n=1$ when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the sequence $\displaystyle 1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{64},\frac{1}{32}\dots$.